# Celery Logging UnicodeDecodeError stuck using 'ascii'

Tags: python-3.x, celery

I'm using celery==4.2.1 with msgpack + msgpack_numpy as serializer on Python3.6

I'm having an issue where the celery task success Logger fails to log due to UnicodeDecodeError.

```
[2018-10-24 14:03:44,944: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] --- Logging error ---
[2018-10-24 14:03:44,944: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] Traceback (most recent call last):
[2018-10-24 14:03:44,944: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] File "/usr/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 994, in emit
    stream.write(msg)
[2018-10-24 14:03:44,944: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-6] UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 925-930: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I am confused as to why the logger is trying to use the 'ascii' codec. To my knowledge, I am not asking it to. These loggers are celery default.

I've seen other questions around this error that suggest setting LANG or LC_ALL and checking the output of `sys.getdefaultencoding()`.

I run `sys.getdefaultencoding()` immediately before the log (I edited the celery source) and I get `utf-8` as expected.

Can anyone point me to sections of the code I should be looking at to change this? From what I understand, 'ascii' should *not* be the default encoding used by the celery loggers.